# Can Ajax and Guzzle be used for live api calls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, guzzle6, guzzle

I'm currently using GuzzleHttp to consume a rest Api.
The Api is returning JSON with cryptocurrency pricing.
Is there any way to asynchronously call, and display the API data using something like Ajax? I currently have to refresh the page to find out if prices have gone up or down.

Here is my simple php code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET','https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10');
$data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(),true);

$numb_of_results = count($data);

for ($i=0; $i<$numb_of_results; $i++) {

echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>".$data[$i]['name']." - ".$data[$i]['price_usd']."</li>";
echo"</ul>";

}

?>
```

Comment: I would put what you have now into a php file/function that gets called by AJAX every so often to check for any updates.. then spit out the output.

Comment: Yes, it can be used, within your XMLHttprequest, place your URL to be the rest API, data type to be json. Infact, you don't need to use PHP for this.

Comment: You should cronjob a script and store the data in a db. Then let PHP display the data you want to see (pulling it from your own db) and you can let javascript update your page every so often. However I would not use PHP to collect the data. I'd do that with python.